# Realm where to close the instance in FirebaseListener Service and in Application class?

Tags: android, realm

I have an Application class where I am initialising(setting default config) my realm instance and then I have one FirebaseListener service class where I am creating a default instance in `onMessageReceived`and using `executetransaction`.

Can anyone please tell me where can I close the realm instance in both of them?